# Finding a cover of a set of points with circles

Tags: algorithm, math

I have N points in a set V given by their coordinates and a number K (0 < K < N). I need to determine K circles (disks) with the same radius R, with their centers in points in the V set. These circles have to 'cover' all the N points and R is the smallest possible.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: sounds like a homework problem - should probably be tagged accordingly.

Comment: What approach did you think about taking?

Comment: @Oded, user577545 thought about coming on SO and getting someone else to solve the problem. a very efficient approach, i might add. sorry user577545 (lots of effort into the name btw), nothing personal, just one too many people seem to be pasting hw problems and posting without sharing half a thought

Comment: I'm a little confused, do you need the circles to be centered on your N points? Are there more points in your set? If the answer to the first and second questions are yes and no, then the solution is trivial, R = min of all distances between your points, otherwise you need to define a constrained optimization problem (see my answer below), and there might be multiple solutions.

Comment: Probably a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Orbling, I disagree. This is a computer science problem, and I don't think it qualifies for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ because it's not a research level related question (i.e. in the same way questions in http://math.stackexchange.com don't qualify for http://mathoverflow.net/)

Comment: @Orbling The [SO faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) specifies "software algorithms". Also compare [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm). When the [Practical Algorithms and Data Structures](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5120/practical-algorithms-and-data-structures?referrer=Ui8Wpa9dvCjQPozYLE14uw2) site launches, then this might well change.

Comment: @AmV: I do not believe it is a computer science problem, it is pure geometry.

Comment: @Orbling, it's computational geometry, which is to say both computer science AND geometry. In fact this problem is discussed in the book Algorithm Design by Kleinberg and Tardos

Comment: @Suresh: No doubt it requires an algorithmic approach.  I would class discrete mathematics techniques, optimisation and such like as maths; the problems were around before computers.

Comment: so was some of theoretical computer science :)

Answer (score 7):

This problem is known as the (discrete) $k$-center problem, and is a well known problem in clustering. While the problem is in general NP-complete, there is a very easy algorithm that generates a solution within factor 2 of the optimal solution in any metric (including the implied 2-D Euclidean distance of the question). It is due to Gonzalez, and is as follows

1. Pick any point
2. Find its farthest neighbor
3. Find the point furthest from these two
4. and so on, till you have k points.

The radius R you end up with is the distance from this last point to the next farthest point. By construction, you are guaranteed to cover all points with disks of radius centered at each of the k points, and by triangle inequality this R is within a factor of 2 of the optimal radius.

If you know that you're in the plane, you can do somewhat better in theory (including getting an exact algorithm in time polynomial in n and exponential in k), but in practice the above algorithm is likely to be the easiest

Comment: Can you shed some light on the proof of factor-2 property? It's clear with `k = 1` (any point can be chosen), but not so much for greater k. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that triangle inequality holds, and that in our soln, all points are contained within $k$ balls of radius R. Notice that the $k+1$th point picked is at least distance R from all others. Assume OPT is different, and uses balls of radius less than R/2. No two of the k+1 points in our soln (k centers+1 pt) can lie within a same cluster of OPT, since each pair of points is >= R apart and so both be within an R/2-ball of a single center of OPT by tri. ineq. Thus, each ball of OPT can contain at most one center of our soln, and OPT needs k+1 balls. contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you described is an instance of a more general optimization problem known as the [covering problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_problem), which can be solved with a [linear programming relaxation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming_relaxation). You might be able to define a cost function that is linear in the radius **R** of your circles (e.g. the sum of the radii for all the circles),  and in [indicator variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) that select what points are chosen to draw the circles. This cost function would be defined subject to constraints that force the circles to cover all the points in your set (check the Wikipedia article on [LP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) for examples)

Once you have defined the cost function and the constraints, there are [several solvers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_.28programming.29_languages) (many of them free) that you can use to solve the optimization problem.

Comment: This is, actually, a special case of LP: [integer linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programs#Integer_unknowns). Thus, LP won't give offer you any good solution here. In fact, this problem is similar to [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), you may find 'Integer linear program formulation' chapter there interesting.

Comment: In what sense is this an ILP problem? The points in the set are given by their coordinates, and the unknowns of the problem are the radii of the circles. The question does not say that the radii must be integers.

Comment: @AmV No (or not only). Unknowns are the points you select. There're N points and you have to draw K circles around them. Each point is either selected or not.

Comment: In fact, you can reduce this to classical [dominating set problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) if you do binary search by `R`.

Comment: The question is not clear about this, but if the points you select and the radii of the circles are the unknowns, then you have to formulate the problem as a mixed integer programming (MIP) problem. In any case, most MIP and IP problems are usually efficiently solved via LP relaxations that rely on a sequence of cutting-plane, branch-and-bound or branch-and-cut steps. In other words, she can (and might only be able to) solve the problem by formulating an LP relaxation and using an LP solver

Comment: @AmV The questions seems pretty clear to me. As for LP relaxation, it all depends on whether OP wants exact solution or not. Unless otherwise noted, we usually assume they do.

Comment: BTW, please do use @username. Now I close this page in the browser and, unless you do, I won't receive any notification about your answer.

Comment: @Nikita, you can get always exact solutions to an MIP/IP problem with an LP relaxation. The way this is done is by defining the LP polytope to be the convex hull of the solution space of the MIP/IP/LP problem, and this always guarantees an exact solution to the original problem. Depending on the problem, this would require the definition a more or less complex polytope (i.e. with more or less facets), but as long as the polytope matches the convex hull, you would get an exact solution.

Comment: @Nikita, (cont.) you can get approximations of the original problem if you build a simpler polytope than the convex hull of the MIP/IP solution space, but you can still measure (sometimes) the integrality gap.

Comment: @AmV Convex hull in N-dimensional space sounds complicated. Not to mention, effective solution here would essentially mean effective solution to set cover problem, which I've not heard about.

Comment: But anyway, +1 for providing some interesting information (even though this doesn't seem like a feasible solution).

Comment: @Nikita, I'm not saying the problem is not hard. MIP/IP problems are in general NP-hard, and this particular problem seems to be NP-complete, but I don't see how an alternative formulation to an LP relaxation would make the problem more tractable. You can both solve or approximate the problem with an LP relaxation, and I hope that's the message I am getting across.