# Optimizing Circle Coverage for Two-Dimensional Data Points

Tags: python, math, set-cover

I have a question. I want to solve the problem with the following conditions.

1. The given data are two-dimensional x, y coordinate data.
2. I'd like to include all this data as a circle (two circles can contain one point in duplicate)
3. The radius of the circle is fixed.
4. The circle should be used to a minimum.

Can I know any programming techniques or algorithms related to this?

I've been Googling, I've been using greed algorithms or heuristic algorithms.

Comment: Please make more obvious what the programming-related aspect of your question is. Try for [ask] and keep in mind that this is a programming community.

Comment: It sounds like your problem can be described simply as 'Given a circle A of unit radius centred on the origin, find the minimum number of circles of radius r < 1 that can cover all points inside A'. Do you need centre coordinates as well? Clearly, there's rotational symmetry which means any set of coordinates is part of an infinite set of equally good solutions. Am I right so far? This looks like it need some mathematical analysis doing first.

Comment: Seems like same problem as [Minimize number of circles to cover set of points](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63697/minimize-number-of-circles-to-cover-set-of-points) in cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Close analogs (rather old) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882202/minimum-number-of-circles-with-radius-r-to-cover-n-points?rq=3), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705922/finding-a-cover-of-a-set-of-points-with-circles)

Comment: @Yunnosch Oh no! I didn't know there was such a rule because it's my first time. Thank you!

Comment: Are you going to act on it and [edit] accordingly?

Comment: @SimonGoater Well, I think I explained it wrong. When the 2D x,y data exist in the 1st quadrant, a circle with a fixed radius wants to wrap it all around. Using the unit to a minimum! Do you need any other additional explanations? Thank you for your response

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I'll take care of it as soon as possible